# Unable to connect to Postgresql on a server

Tags: ssh, postgresql, remote-access

On Digital Ocean I'm able to connect to Postgresql:

```
psql -d my_db -U my_name
```

for which it asks me a password and I get in successfully. But from my local computer I'm unable:

```
psql -d my_db -U my_name -h x.x.x.x
```

Nothing happens at all. Here's my /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: and you've opened the appropriate port in your firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check and make sure postregsql is listening on your interface IP (not just 127.0.0.1).

```
ss -ltn
```

If not, modify the `listen_addresses` to * or the IP you want.  These settings should be in `postgresql.conf` file generally located in the postgresql data directory.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: I think yes --> `LISTEN      0      128    127.0.0.1:5432                      *:*`

Comment: actually, that's only on local interface? how to get it to listen on any ip interface?

Comment: Check you postgresql.conf file, there should be a `listen_addresses` directive you can modify to your IP or to * for all addresses on that server.

Comment: there's no "listen_addresses".

Comment: hmm, sure you are in postgresql.conf (not pg_hba.conf)?  if it's not there, try adding it.

Comment: it was pg_hba.conf. `postgresql.conf` doesn't exist on my server. why?

Comment: try running `SHOW config_file;` and see if it tells you at least where they should be.  you may need to be logged in as postgresql or have root priv to see them.